# Proving a removable discontinuity exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

So I made up the following function as a thought exercise (for myself).

$$f(x) = 1\hspace{0.3cm} \forall\hspace{0.1cm} x = 1,2,3 \hspace{0.4cm}\text{and} \hspace{0.4cm} -1 \hspace{0.3cm}\forall \hspace{0.1cm}x = 4,5,6.$$

I have already proven that this function is not continuous.

But how would I go about proving (or disproving—honestly I have no idea) that the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=  ?$$

Comment: Is the only condition the value of $f$ at those $6$ points? Because there are so many functions that are continuous and attain those values..

Comment: On which set is your function defined ? $\{1; \dots ; 6\}$ or $[1;6]$ ?

Comment: the domain of the function is on {1,2,3,4,5,6}

Answer (score 0):

With the usual (discrete) topology on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the function *is* continuous (like *every* function with that domain), and the limit does *not* exist (since it is not even meaningful to ask about the limit at a point which is not an accumulation point of the domain).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Take a = 1. If x = 4 and delta  = 5,  that implies 2 <  epsilon , which is a contradiction (let epsilon = 1).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. For any $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta > 0$, for example $\delta = 1/4$, such that $|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in D_f$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$. This is because there is only one such $x$, namely the point $x=a$ itself, and this causes $|f(x)-f(a)|$ to be *zero*, which is certainly less than $\epsilon$. Thus the function satisifies the definition of what it means to be continuous at $a$.

Comment: Yes, you're right — I apologize. I see that I made an error in my proof.

Answer (score -1):

For $x\to 3^-$, f(x) is not defined.
Similarly, For $x\to 3^+$, f(x) is not defined.
But, at $x=3$, $f(x)=1$

For limit to exist at $x=3$, function must attain a value (same value) at $x\to3^-$ and $x\to 3^+$, which may be different from value of function at **3**.

For eg., consider $$\lim_{x\to3^-}=\lim_{x\to3^+}=p$$ And, $$f(3)=q$$
So, Limit exists at $x\to3$ and its value is p. $$\lim_{x\to3}=p$$

> This is called as **missing point discontinuity**, since, **f(3)** is not **q**, but **p**, i.e. *a missing point*.
>    It comes under removable discontinuity.

---

**edit:**

Also, there are cases where a function is not defined for one side, in such cases, we go for one-sided limit.
For eg. Consider $$f(x)=\sqrt x$$ f(x) is not defined for $x\to 0^-$
So, $$\lim_{x\to 0}=f(0^+)=0$$ i.e., limit is equal to value of f(x) for $x\to 0^+$.

> This is a one-sided definition of limits, used when there is a domain restriction at **boundary points** for a function.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Formally, how is it you come up with your one-side limit assertions? Intuitively, your answer is a great help though!

Comment: that is what we were taught... :-)

Comment: sorry? I'm not sure I understand. I was asking how your frame your answer in terms of delta-epsilon

Comment: Delta-Epsilon was not really introduced...what i recollect is we used to find out where f(x) approaches just before and just after the point, where limit is to be found

Comment: isnt this what limit really means..?

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. For example, the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, $x \ge 0$, satisfies $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$ even though the left-hand limit $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$ doesn't exist. The criterion that the limits from the left and from the right must be equal is only valid when the function is defined arbitrarily close to the point in question *on both sides*.

Comment: @HansLundmark we refer to only one-sided limit in such cases

Comment: No, we don't! Or rather, the limit is automatically equal to the one-sided limit in such a case.

Comment: yeah, that is what i meant. limit will be equal to value of $\sqrt x$ for $x\to 0^+$, i.e. 0

Comment: this definition worked pretty fine for us...

Comment: @HansLundmark edited to address this point.